# error: member access into incomplete type : forward declaration of

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have two classes in the same .cpp file:

```
// forward
class B;

class A {       
   void doSomething(B * b) {
      b->add();
   }
};

class B {
   void add() {
      ...
   }
};
```

The forward does not work, I cannot compile.

I get this error:

```
error: member access into incomplete type 'B'
note: forward declaration of 'B'
```

I'm using clang compiler (clang-500.2.79).

**I don't want to use multiple files (.cpp and .hh), I'd like to code just on one .cpp.**

**I cannot write the class B before the class A.**

Do you have any idea of how to resolve my problem ?

Comment: Move the function body of `A::doSomething` after the definition of `class B`.

Comment: I speak about that in the thread : "I cannot write the class B before the class A.". I use a example code to explain my problem. In my real code, I have a pointer to my class B in my class A. So, if I write the class B before the class A, the problem would be the same !

Comment: Names beginning with an underscore, such as `_b`, should be avoided. They can be used by the compiler/standard library in the global namespace; additionally, you should **never** use identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, such as `_B` (also reserved).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Move `doSomething` definition outside of its class declaration and after `B` and also make `add` accessible to `A` by `public`-ing it or `friend`-ing it.

```
class B;

class A
{
    void doSomething(B * b);
};

class B
{
public:
    void add() {}
};

void A::doSomething(B * b)
{
    b->add();
}
```

Comment: Had a similar issue. I'd forgotten to include the header (from another class) in the .cpp

Comment: What if A is a templated class? Then you can't really just move it outside of the class declaration...

Comment: @Volte , just my case! Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

You must have the *definition* of class `B` before you use the class. How else would the compiler know that there exists a function `B::add`?

Either define class `B` before class `A`, or move the body of `A::doSomething` to after class `B` have been defined, like

```
class B;

class A
{
    B* b;

    void doSomething();
};

class B
{
    A* a;

    void add() {}
};

void A::doSomething()
{
    b->add();
}
```