# Error: Member access into incomplete type 'Snail'

Tags: c++

I have this error in the screenshots below. I have tried listing the constructor and functions in the hpp file and defining the functions in the cpp file but that did not work either. I have no idea what to do to fix this. I think that the error has to do with maybe the headers and the order that they might have been placed in. Everything in both of the classes are done and completed. The classes are both in separate files called Cell.hpp and Snail.hpp.

In the Cell.hpp I have :

```
#ifndef Cell_hpp
#define Cell_hpp

#include "TheGreatSnailRaceParams.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Cell.hpp"
#include "Snail.hpp"
#include "CellBase.hpp"


class Cell : public CellBase{


public:
    Cell() = default; // default constructor
    
    Cell(params::settings *s) { // parameterized constructor
        settings_colors = &s->c; // construct cell
        current = &s->c.at(0);
    }
    
  params::color* current;
  std::vector<params::color>* settings_colors; // unsigned int color requirement

    void nextColor() override{
        this->color = current->nextColor;
        current = &settings_colors->at(this->color);
}
    
    void nextOrientation(Snail *s) override{
        int change_orientation = current->deltaOrientation;
        int absolute_value;

        if(change_orientation < 0){
            absolute_value = (-1) * (change_orientation);
            while(absolute_value > 0){
                s->o.go_clockwise(); // error message here: Member access into incomplete type 'Snail'
                absolute_value = absolute_value - 1;
            }
        }

        if(change_orientation > 0){
            absolute_value = change_orientation;
            s->o.go_counterclockwise(); // error message here: Member access into incomplete type 'Snail'
            absolute_value = absolute_value - 1;
        }
    }
private:
  

};

#endif /* Cell_hpp */

//In the Snail.hpp I have:


#ifndef SNAIL_H_
#define SNAIL_H_
#include "Board.hpp"
#include "SnailBase.hpp"
#include "TheGreatSnailRaceParams.hpp"



class Snail : public SnailBase{


public:
    Snail() = default; // default constructor
    Snail(orientation init_orientation, SnailBase::location location, unsigned int board_size){
        boardSize = board_size;
        snail_obj->row = std::get <0> (location);
        snail_obj->col = std::get <1> (location);
        o = init_orientation;
    }
    orientation o;
    location current_location;
    Snail* snail_obj;
    int row, col;
    location loc;
    
    void step(Cell* c) override{
        c->nextOrientation(this); // change orientation
        c->nextColor(); // changes to next color
        if(o.current == 0){
            this->snail_obj->col = this->snail_obj->col + 1;
        }

        if(o.current == 1){
            this->snail_obj->row = this->snail_obj->row + 1;
        }

        if(o.current == 2){
            this->snail_obj->col = this->snail_obj->col - 1;
        }

        if(o.current == 3){
            this->snail_obj->row = this->snail_obj->row - 1;
        }
        if(this->snail_obj->row == -1){
            this->snail_obj->row = this->boardSize - 1;
        }

        if(this->snail_obj->row == 0){
            this->snail_obj->row = this->boardSize;
        }

        if(this->snail_obj->col == -1){
            this->snail_obj->col = this->boardSize - 1;
        }

        if(this->snail_obj->col == 0){
            this->snail_obj->col = this->boardSize;
        }
    }
    unsigned int get_orientation() override{
        return o.current;
    }
    
    virtual location get_location() override{
        std::tuple<int, int> current_location (snail_obj->row, snail_obj->col);
        return current_location;
    }
    
private:
     unsigned int boardSize;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: member access into incomplete type : forward declaration of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962812/error-member-access-into-incomplete-type-forward-declaration-of)

Comment: I actually solved it. I had to forward both the classes into each other and then define in the cpp file.

Comment: Tip: You can ditch all the `this->` chaff. That's only necessary when there's *variable shadowing*, which you don't have here.

Comment: Also why does Snail have a Snail inside itself? Where does `snail_obj` get initialized?