# Member acces into incomplete type C++

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I am trying to have two classes in C++ - class1, class2. I want class2 to contain an instance of class1 and class1 to have a shared_ptr to the class2 – a pointer to the object, in which it is contained.
So I have following 4 files:

class2.hpp

```
#include "class1.hpp"
#include <vector>

class class2 {
    friend class1;
private:
    class1 data;
    std::vector<int> numbers;
public:
    class2();
};
```

class2.cpp

```
#include "class2.hpp"

class2::class2() : data(std::shared_ptr<class2>(this)){}
```

class1.hpp

```
#include <memory>

class class2;
class class1 {
    std::shared_ptr<class2> ptr;
    class1(std::shared_ptr<class2> ptr);
    void add_item(int i);
};
```

and class1.cpp

```
#include "class1.hpp"

class1::class1(std::shared_ptr<class2> ptr) {
    ptr = ptr;
}

void class1::add_item(int i) {
    ptr->add_item(6); //Member access into incomplete type 'std::__1::shared_ptr<class2>::element_type' (aka 'class2')
}
```

I am getting the error in function add_item. I think that it has something to do with the forward declaration of class2.
I found this related topic, but there they dont split the files into header file.
[error: member access into incomplete type : forward declaration of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962812/error-member-access-into-incomplete-type-forward-declaration-of)

If I understand well, I should put the function add_item after definition of class2, but I dont how to solve it, if I want to have the files splitted like this. Is it possible?
Please note, that I am trying to solve this in bigger project, this is very simplified.

Thanks is advance for any answer.

Comment: avoid any  `#include` in your .hpp files (use forward declarations). And put your `#include`s in the cpp files

Comment: You forgot to include `class2.hpp`, a simple typo.

Comment: `class1.cpp` should include `class2.hpp`. `class1.hpp` should not include `class2.hpp`

Comment: *"I should put the function add_item after definition of class2"* -- right. Exactly that, but from a flipped perspective. You should put the definition of `class2` before the definition of `add_item`. Then the question should become how do you put (or include) the definition of `class2` at the beginning of `class1.cpp`?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<class2>(this)` is a definite no-no - you can't hand over ownership of `*this` to a `shared_ptr` - it aready has an owner.

Comment: Might be a bit of information overload for this particular question, but still relevant: [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/)

Answer (score 2):

Forward declare class1 in class2.hpp and include class2.h in class1.cpp.

class2.hpp:

```
//#include "class1.hpp"       // REMOVE!
#include <vector>

class class1;                 // ADD
class class2 {
...
```

class2.cpp:

```
#include "class2.hpp"
#include "class1.hpp"         // ADD
```

class1.hpp:

```
#include <memory>

class class2;                // OK
```

class1.cpp:

```
#include "class1.hpp"
#include "class2.hpp"         // ADD

class1::class1(std::shared_ptr<class2> ptr) {
    ptr = ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want class2 to contain an instance of class1 and class1 to have a shared_ptr to the class2 – a pointer to the object, in which it is contained.

No, you should not want that. There is no reason for a sub-object to own (even in shared capacity) their super object.

Furthermore, you cannot access members of an incomplete class. You must define the class first.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I define the class first if they are in separate files?

Comment: @TobyV. Include the header that defines the class. There's a pre-processor directive for that purpose.