# Why can we use a forward declared function but not instantiate a forward declared class?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

While reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19962812/6360521) I was wondering why calling a function previously forward-declarated is possible like in this example

```
int f(int x, int y); // forward declaration


int main()
{
    return f(2,3);
}

int f(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

but instantiating or calling a member variable of a class previously forward-declared is not possible like in the example

```
class Foo; // forward declaration

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    return 0;
}

class Foo
{
    int x = 3;
};
```

My thaughts are that a function is just like an address, which is defined when the forward declaration is done (for example f() is assigned `0xABC`). Then when parsing the `return f(x,y)` line the compiler just injects that address `0xABC` in the binary code and then later when parsing the declaration of the function the compiler start inputting the instruction starting from address `0xABC`.

However, when parsing the class Foo forward declaration if the compiler assigns to that class to some memory say `0xDEF`, then when it parses `Foo foo` it will not know how much space to allocate since all the members of the class were not defined yet so the compiler doesn't know how much space to allocate in total

I don't really know anything about compilers, so is this correct?

Comment: One thing that differs between functions and objects, is that objects needs space in memory to be created. And for the compiler to know how much space will be needed, it needs the full definition of the objects class. To call a function all the compiler needs is the function signature.

Comment: Your thoughts were correct.  When you declare an object the compiler needs to know how much space to allocate.  You can't do that with just a declaration.  With a function, it just needs to make sure you called the function with the correct parameters and return value.  You only need a declaration for that.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: "*My thaughts are that ...*" - mostly correct. Though, it is the *linker* not the *compiler* that fills in the address of a function call. The compiler doesn't know where the actual function body resides. It just outputs an object file that contains a reference to the function call. Once the linker brings all of the compiled object files together and decides where each code will exist in the final executable, then it replaces function call references with their actual addresses as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, good point. Perhaps I should have said "the compiler injects the symbol..." and not "the compiler injects the address..."?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are mostly correct, but you don't need to think about how compilers work.

By forward declaring a function, you make its signature available to the rest of the code. This means its name, return value, and parameter types are known, and that's all you need syntactically to call that function.

By forward declaring a class, you only make it known that its name refers to a type. That enables you to use it in various contexts. For example, you can declare (but not define) a function with that class as a parameter type or as the return type. Or you can define a pointer to that class, because the type a pointer points to doesn't matter as long as you don't try to dereference it. Or you can use it as argument to a typename in a template, as long as that template doesn't actually use it (but it could define a pointer to it or declare a function with it as parameter type and so on).

Knowing only that some particular name refers to a class, you cannot deduce anything about its contents (and yes, its size) or how to actually use it.